# ssl on android strange issue

Tags: android, ssl

I am trying to upload a file to some url using ssl. I use this code to set trust manager -

```
public static void trustAll () {
    TrustManage[] trustEverythingTrustManager = new TrustManager[] {
        new X509TrustManager() {

            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
            String authType) throws CertificateException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
            String authType) throws CertificateException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
            }

        }
    };

    SSLContext sc;
    try {
        sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sc.init(null, trustEverythingTrustManager, new SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

and this one to set host name verifier -

```
public static HostnameVerifier DO_NOT_VERIFY = new HostnameVerifier() {

    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
        return true;
    }
};
```

then i am opening connection like this -

```
URL url = new URL("some_url");
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
// check if this is https or just http
if (url.getProtocol().toLowerCase().equals("https")) {
    trustAll();
    HttpsURLConnection https = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    https.setHostnameVerifier(DO_NOT_VERIFY);
    connection = https;
} else {
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
}
```

After i get the connection i use it to upload the data. Is i use http everything is ok but when i try https i get the following exception -

Write error: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe
java.io.IOException: Write error: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe
at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.nativewrite(Native Method)
at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.access$600(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:55)
at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLOutputStream.write(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:565)
at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:82)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpOutputStream.write(HttpURLConnection.java:652)
at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:101)

The strange thing is that i don't get exception all the time. When i try to upload small files (200K) it's working O.K. or it's crashing very rare but when i try to upload bigger ones (more than 1MB) i get the exception almost every time.

Any ideas ?

Comment: I also found similar issue here http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/ea5790641481c8d8/38eea394ca62faa9?lnk=gst&q=Unable+to+upload+multipart+file+HttpURLConnection+Chunked+Streaming+Mode+is+giving+broken+pipe+exception.#38eea394ca62faa9

Comment: i reported issue to android with demo project but still no response :(
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8625

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The guys from android reported that is bug in android sdk http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8625.