# Android OutOfMemoryException while uploading file on HTTPS

Tags: android, ssl, https, out-of-memory

I am having troubles while uploading files via https (HttpsURLConnection).
Using the same code with HttpURLConnection works like a charm.

here is the stack:

```
ERROR/dalvikvm-heap(29984): Out of memory on a 20932172-byte allocation.
INFO/dalvikvm(29984): "UploadingManager" prio=5 tid=9 RUNNABLE
INFO/dalvikvm(29984):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x2b085018 self=0x3d4de8
INFO/dalvikvm(29984):   | sysTid=30027 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=3868056
INFO/dalvikvm(29984):   at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.expand(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:~91)
INFO/dalvikvm(29984):   at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:216)
INFO/dalvikvm(29984):   at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.RetryableOutputStream.write(RetryableOutputStream.java:60)
INFO/dalvikvm(29984):   at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:99)
INFO/dalvikvm(29984):   at com.my.app.utils.UploadingManager$UploadingThread.run(UploadingManager.java:568)
```

And here is the code:
Initializing connection:

```
URL url = new URL(url_to_send); 
trustAllHosts();
connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setHostnameVerifier(DO_NOT_VERIFY);
connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(maxBufferSize);
```

I am using the same code for establishing "trustall" ssl connection as mentioned in here:
[ssl on android strange issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820284/ssl-on-android-strange-issue) (I know that they are facing similar issue but I want to make sure that I am not making any mistake during the upload)

And here is the code for upload:

```
 File uploaded_file = new File(pathToOurFile);
 file_input = new FileInputStream(uploaded_file);

 output_byte = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

 int maxBufferSize = 20 * 1024;
 bytesAvailable = file_input.available();
 bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
 buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

 // Read file
 bytesRead = file_input.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
 already_send += bytesRead;

 while (bytesRead > 0) {

     output_byte.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize); < ----Exception occurs here
     bytesAvailable = file_input.available();
     bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
     bytesRead = file_input.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
     already_send += bytesRead;

 }

 output_byte.writeBytes(endBoundary);
 output_byte.flush();
```

Have you got any idea why am I getting OutOfMemoryException?

Regards,
Peter

**EDIT1:**
I have noticed that if I omit:

```
connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(maxBufferSize);
```

using the working httpUrlConnection I am falling into same issue.
I know that sending same message using ssl will generate longer content-length so I have changed the chunk size to **2 * maxBufferSize** or even **20 * maxBufferSize** but this makes no difference to me :/

Answer (score 1):

How big is the file you are uploading? It seems that you are trying to write around ~20MB to `output_byte` buffer.

Also you are writing wrong number of bytes to your output.

`read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);` line doesn't guarantee `bufferSize` amount of bytes will be read. The amount read is returned from the call above so:

```
output_byte.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
```

should be instead:

```
output_byte.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
```

So for example if you read 1024bytes and try to write 20*1024 bytes each time, for a 1MB file you will have have 20 times the output bytes. This could cause `OutOfMemory` error.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
Anyway, I am pretty sure that bufferSize == bytesRead, please note that I am using this piece of code:
bytesAvailable = file_input.available();
bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
to make sure bufferSize == bytesRead.

File size is about 15-50 MB

Comment: ok, that explains it. It seems you read the file in 20*1024 chunks but sending it in 1 chunk. You should send it in smaller parts. Android apps have around 16-64 mb memory limit forced by the OS. You cannot change it.

Comment: Judging by Wireshark logs I suppose that I am also sending multiple chunks. The strange thing is that using normal HttpURLConnection I am able to send even 100 MB file using same code. Switching to Http(S)URLConnection causes all the problems